# ASP.NET Web API 2 minutes to load doc page on new project

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET (.NET framework v4.7.2) Web API. When I debug and try to access the values doc page (`/Help/Api/GET-api-Values`), it takes between 1.7 min and 2 min to load (time according to the network tab).

I have tried it with and without updating the NuGet packages. I have tried FF and Chrome. I have tried it on my SATA and my SSD. I have re-created the project several times. I cannot get this to go any faster and I have not made any changes or addition to the project at all, all I do is create the project and hit debug. I have checked my resources and I am hovering around 40% CPU and 33% memory so it's not a resource issue. I should also mention that going from the home page to the api list page (/Help) works fine.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Clean install (or moving to pro) was the solution.

I updated my VS and a SR developer helped me look at the issue during a mentoring session, we could not get it to work so after 40min he suggested a clean install and said to try my pro license while I was at it. I suspect it was the clean install rather then moving to pro but I can't say 100% it was one or the other though. Unless pro lets vs use multiple cores because on community edition it was using 1 core and maxing that core out so my cpu looked ok at a glance but a deeper dive showed issues.